# monitoring processes writing elements in a queue

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing, monitoring

I am writting a GUI with python.

At some point I want to speed up some time-consuming taks, so I used multiprocessing like this:

```
resultsQueue = multiprocessing.Queue()


p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=proc1, args=(some_arguments, resultsQueue))
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=proc2, args=(some_arguments, resultsQueue))
p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=proc3, args=(some_arguments, resultsQueue))
p4 = multiprocessing.Process(target=proc4, args=(some_arguments, resultsQueue))
p5 = multiprocessing.Process(target=proc5, args=(some_arguments, resultsQueue))

p1.daemon = True
p2.daemon = True
p3.daemon = True
p4.daemon = True
p5.daemon = True

p1.start()
p2.start()
p3.start()
p4.start()
p5.start()

self.processes += [p1]
self.processes += [p2]
self.processes += [p3]
self.processes += [p4]
self.processes += [p5]

for p in self.processes:
    p.join()
```

Basically, each process consists in a big loop, doing some calculations and putting results in the resultsQueue, something like this:

```
def proc1(some_arguments, resultsQueue):
    #the long loop here
    for i in xrange(....):
        #do some calculations
        resultsQueue.put(the_result)
    resultsQueue.put("Done")
```

As you can see, I am trying to add a "flag", at the end of each process, "Done".

However, I am stuck, because I do not know how to monitor the processes from the main GUI in order to show a progress bar, or to show a message etc, at the same time that the processes are ending one by one....

Comment: Why not a shared structure to notify the state of each subprocess to the main process ?

Comment: yeah sure, but give me more details because I do not have any idea how to proceed :D what do you mean with a shared structure?? I need more info :)

Comment: a shared value of the last processed `i` for each process: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Comment: thanks for your comment but I am afraid that I stil do not see how to force the processes to communicate with the main thread of the GUI and asynchronously tell that they have finished, to update a progress bar then.....